# Scroll to Collapse View without Toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I'm making a layout similar to recent android's status bar.

[image]

I have two `Views` inside container. `ViewPager` and `RecyclerView`.
The default behavior should be that when I scroll `RecyclerView`, I want `ViewPager` to decrease in size and vice versa.

[image]

**Logic:**

```
viewPagerMaxHeight = 200;
if scrollTop
  is ViewPager.height > viewPagerMaxHeight?
    YES: Prevent Scroll and Decrease ViewPager size apropriatry
    No: Scroll RecyclerView
if scrollBottom
  did we scroll to position 0?
    YES: Start increasing ViewPager size
    No: Scroll RecyclerView
```

**Few notes:**
 - `RecyclerView` contains items of various size.
 - Sometimes items are removed and added
 - It is a simple RecyclerView, not
   like in notifications where they collapse on each other.

I can construct most of the logic myself but I could not make a proper listener for `RecyclerView` which will return direction and amount that was scrolled.
preventing `RecyclerView` from scrolling is a bonus

**EDIT:**

I have made an example on [github](https://github.com/mpa4hu/ScrollToCollapse)

```
v.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        Log.e("scrollY", ""+scrollY);
        Log.e("oldScrollY", ""+oldScrollY);
        Log.e("currentHeight", ""+currentHeight);
        if(scrollY == 200) {
            Log.e("==200", "JU");
        } else if (scrollY < 200) {
            Log.e("<200", ""+currentHeight);

            if(currentHeight < fullHeight) {
                Log.e("current<full", Integer.toString(deltaScroll));
                deltaScroll = oldScrollY - scrollY;
                currentHeight = currentHeight + deltaScroll;
                if(currentHeight > fullHeight) {
                    currentHeight = fullHeight;
                }
                ku.getLayoutParams().height = currentHeight;
                ku.requestLayout();
            }
            v.scrollTo(0, 200);
        } else if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
            Log.e("Scroll DOWN", "" + Integer.toString(scrollY));
            deltaScroll = scrollY - oldScrollY;
            currentHeight = currentHeight - deltaScroll;
            if(currentHeight > minHeight) {
                ku.getLayoutParams().height = currentHeight;
                ku.requestLayout();
                v.scrollTo(0, 200);

            } else {
                currentHeight = minHeight;
                ku.getLayoutParams().height = minHeight;
                ku.requestLayout();
            }

        }
    }
});
```

I'm setting padding for `RecycleView` and scrolling `NestedScrollView` to the first item so the padding is not visible. this allows me to scroll TOP even when already at the TOP.

Everything seems to work, but as you will notice scrolling is "jumpy" when scrolling slowly (won't happen if scrolled fast enough).
My guess is that is happening because `NestedScrollView` itself changes height and while scrolling up for example, scroll down happens as well.

Comment: Mixing RecyclerView and NestedScrollView often leads to 'jumpy' performance. Can you please elaborate what are you using the ViewPager for? And if possible share your layout XML....

Comment: Look into Coordinator layout

Comment: @AbhishekSingh there is a github which contains all my views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above is totally doable with the help of `ConstraintLayout` and `Guideline`. So when you scroll up set the guideline programmatically to minimum and when you scroll down set the guildline back to normal.

Below is a xml sample for the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerTopGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerBottomGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewPagerBottomGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewPagerTopGuideline">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewPagerBottomGuideline"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can place the views inside a `NestedScrollView`as well. Then onscroll you can set the guideline like this

```
 @BindView(R.id.viewPagerBottomGuideline)
Guideline guideLine;//have Used ButterKnife

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideLine.getLayoutParams();
            params.guidePercent = 0.20f; // 45% // range: 0 <-> 1
            guideLine.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I have just implemented on scroll up, then you would have to implement the same for scroll down as well.

Comment: I cannot use CoordinatorLayout or ConstraintLayout.

Comment: While I cannot use it, this qualifies as a correct answer

Answer (score 3):

According to your current code:

> Everything seems to work, but as you will notice scrolling is "jumpy" when scrolling slowly...

**YES** , this is because the method `onScrollChange` might be called a number of times when a user scroll slowly (due to the system misinterpret that like `scroll ==> stop ==> scroll ==> stop ==> scroll ==> stop ==>...`)  and therefore the logic inside the method will be executed a number of times or/and altogether and since there are calculations and logic (`if` and `else`) this may lead to an effect in the responsiveness of the UI. This will not occur if the the user will scroll fast it will called probably once, interpreted as a single scroll.

**SOLUTION:**

1. Reduce some tiresome calculations and logic in your code if possible.
2. Use the [`Coordinator Layout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) as a root layout instead of `LinearLayout` and set some [`Behaviours`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html) that your child `Views` should follow inside the [`CoordinatorLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html). Otherwise prepare the logic using a `boolean` that will make sure that the contents of your method `onSrollChange` will not be called a number of times but only once when the user finally finishes the whole slow scroll.

Comment: I cannot use CoordinatorLayout or ConstraintLayout. number of calls is not a problem. I dont think you spent time to inspect my code.

Comment: i read your code! Even in github but the issue is the method being called a number of times! Why don't you try an animation that will load only if the previous animation has finished and any updates of an animation will be saved later after a previous animation has finished. This is user friendly too!

Comment: sounds like an idea, and since there is little time to award bounty here you go

Comment: Ooooh thanks and **Happy Coding!**. Its my first answer with a bounty!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use CoOrdinate Layout as you main layout (root layout.).
then All you need to do is to set this behaviour some thing like Collapsing Toolbar via Java or coding. I have implemented same thing and [this](https://github.com/teocci/AndroidGuidenotes/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout) link really helped me alot. please click on the link and give it a try.

(https://github.com/teocci/AndroidGuidenotes/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)

Comment: While this link may answer the question , please provide substantial part here.

Comment: I cannot use CoordinatorLayout or ConstraintLayout